# Refreshing web page causes it to crash

Tags: node.js, backend

When I refresh the page, the page crashes every time, I have tried replacing 'end' with 'write', have I just not learnt enough code yet to prevent this? It seems like in the tutorial I am following that this should be working whenever I refresh. Initially starting the webpage is no problem though

```
const http = require('http');

//connection settings
//port is a end point of communication
const port = 3000;
// hostname: IP associated with any deivce on a network
const hostname = '127.0.0.1';

const respond = (request, response) => {

    //response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    //writeHead (stațus code, {headers})
    //response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' })
    if (request.url === '/about') {
        response.end("about")
    }

    if (request.url === '/') {
        response.end("home page");

    }
    response.end("error page")
    /*
    socket.on('error', function(e){
        console.log(e);
    });
    was searching up a solution but this^ did not work
*/
};

const url = require('url');



const server = http.createServer(respond);

server.listen(port, hostname, () => { console.log('Server listening on port 3000') })
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RJFs.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the `response.end("error page")`. That's running unconditionally on every request, even when one of your `if` statements is true.

Perhaps you meant to do an `if...else if...else`? This would fix your problem.

```
if (request.url === '/about') {
  response.end('about');
} else if (request.url === '/') {
  response.end('home page');
} else {
  response.end('error page');
}
```

Comment: I would accept your answer but I have to wait the grace period, but just wondering why does the page not crash in the inital start up but does when I refresh if the last response.end(...) runs unconditionally? Thanks btw

Comment: Technically it does crash the first time, but it crashes after it returns the response. So from the browser's perspective you see the first page load properly, but if you check your shell you'll see that the node script has crashed after the first load, as soon as it hits the second `response.end`.

Comment: ooohh alright that makes sense, thanks